# Python: Floating Point images / alternative to matlab's im2double?

Tags: python, image, matlab, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to convert some matlab code to python and the `im2double` function is giving me trouble. It takes an image and returns a matrix with the pixels using doubles instead of ints.

Currently I'm manipulating my images with PIL. It has a `convert` method that can take `'F'` as parameter, but all it does is convert the integer value `255` to `255.0`. Useless as far as I can tell.

The problem I have is that I'm doing some image manipulation and then have to save them. I can normalize my values so that they fall into the 0-255 range, but I lose some precision. It's small enough that it shouldn't normally matter, but here, it does.

I've tried using the 'tiff' file format and that didn't work out well. Though I can write/read to it, the results I get are not the right ones, which I can only get at the moment converting the pixels to 255 which results in a loss of precision, as I said previously. I also tried this `'SPIDER'` file format thing I found on google previously that PIL supports though I couldn't open the image on an editor to check how it was doing.

Comment: You've gotta convert to 0-255 range for the purpose of writing out the pixels eventually don't you?

Comment: Yes, but I was hoping I only had to do that due to the fact that I don't have a suitable file format to work with right now. For example, you can actually do a `im.show(floating_point_image)` on matlab without having to convert it.

Comment: Your computer only has a range 0-255 for red, green, and blue. It simply cannot display any more detail then that.

Comment: Really? Not that I'm doubting you, but I'm genuinely surprised because the code I'm reading has some data for the colors stored in .mat files that has a precision greater than 1/255. As in, I can't SEE the difference looking at the picture generated from the .mat file and the color image converted to black and white, but loading the original values and operating on them, I can show with the code that there's actually difference in the images in some pixels. So, in other words, in other to store this significant difference, I can't use images, despite the code being useful for that? Huh. Weird.

Comment: Also, what about file formats like exr or rgbe?

Comment: I don't know what Matlab is doing, but I've never seen any computer based color system with anything but the 1-255 range. This raises the question of why you are trying to store this data as images.

Comment: I see that some formats do exist with more precision. They will be still be converted for drawing. However, I could see how doing image manipulation would need the extra precision.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this properly in Python will to use [Numpy](https://web.archive.org/web/20121108212849/http://numpy.scipy.org:80/). You can read images via [PIL into numpy](https://web.archive.org/web/20130130052205/http://scipy.org/Cookbook/PIL) arrays. At this point a wide range of Matlab like matrix operations become available to you via numpy/scipy. Changing the precision of the array is simply a matter of switching the arrays datatype via numpy. Recent [releases](https://web.archive.org/web/20200809073104/http://effbot.org:80/zone/pil-changes-116.htm) of PIL include the patch from Travis Oliphant to allow you to do this without extra hackery.

Saving the data to a more commonly readable image format can be achieved by using a floating point TIFF without loss of precision. I use the [GDAL library](https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html) to interface to multiple image format writers/readers. If you want lossless compression TIFF can compress using zlib as well.

Comment: if I understand what's going on correctly, the OP probably wants to read his source .mat directly into numpy arrays where he can do the operations without significant loss of precision and then output into PIL.

Comment: I'm already using ndarrays. The problem is, once PIL reads the image, I lose the precision because it converts the information to 0-255. I can load the .mat files easily with `scipy.io`. The only way this would be "right" would be if there was no way to get more precision out of a 'jpg' image like @Winston Ewert suggested above. Then that means I can only get the necessary information from non image files.

Comment: @idontlikeyourmatlab, if its already in a jpeg file, the precision is already lost. In fact since jpeg is lossly you've already suffered a considerable loss of precision.

Comment: @Winston Ewert I guess it might be. I'll leave it open for the time being in case someone has a more helpful answer tho.

Comment: Coming from image processing world, I avoid storing real data in JPEG like a plague, unless demonstrating fidelity loss is the purpose. You can save TIFF files in Floating point - I typically use GDAL for this purpose (See modified answer).